# What’s the difference between remove and delete?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

For example, I have a TypeORM entity `Profile`:

```
@Entity()
class Profile {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    gender: string;

    @Column()
    photo: string;

    @OneToOne(type => User, { cascade: true })
    @JoinColumn()
    user: User;
}
```

And I’m not sure which one should I use to delete a user profile?

```
Profile.remove(profile)
Profile.delete(profile)
```

What is the difference between the `remove` and `delete` methods in TypeORM?

Comment: I guess they have the meanings described here? https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entity-manager-api.md `remove()` being the one you should use when you have a profile object and `delete()` deleting based on criteria.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

From [Repo](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/repository-api.md):

- `remove` - Removes a given entity or array of entities. It removes all given entities in a single transaction (in the case of entity, manager is not transactional).

Example:

```
await repository.remove(user);
await repository.remove([
    category1,
    category2,
    category3
]);
```

- `delete` - Deletes entities by entity id, ids or given conditions:

Example:

```
await repository.delete(1);
await repository.delete([1, 2, 3]);
await repository.delete({ firstName: "Timber" });
```

As stated in example [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/delete-query-builder.md):

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .delete()
    .from(User)
    .where("id = :id", { id: 1 })
    .execute();
```

> Which means you should use `remove` if it contains an array of Entities.
>
> While you should use `delete` if you know the condition.

---

Additionally, as @[James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10187284/james) stated in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246615/what-s-the-difference-between-remove-and-delete/54246681#comment100999984_54246681) `Entity Listener` such as `@BeforeRemove` and `@AfterRemove` listeners only triggered when the entity is removed using `repository.remove`.

Similarly, `@BeforeInsert`, `@AfterInsert`, `@BeforeUpdate`, `@AfterUpdate` only triggered when the entity is inserted/updated using `repository.save`.

Source: [Entity Listeners and Subscribers](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#beforeinsert)

Comment: do lifecycle methods happen the same on both?

Comment: Also be aware that `repository.delete` does not trigger `@Before/After Remove` listeners, only `repository.remove` does.

Same way, `repository.update` does NOT trigger `@Before/After Update` listeners, only `repository.save` does.

Comment: The information that `Before/After-Insert` only trigger with `repository.save` is incorrect! I have tried and it did trigger with `repository.insert` too. From [this discussion](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2237#issuecomment-393887523), pleerock indirectly confirm that insert will also trigger the decorator.

Comment: @nyotoarif Is `.insert` using Subscribers now? If it does you could request documentation changes for which listener was affected. I've checked [Docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#beforeinsert) and it still states that only `.save` triggered them. I haven't got the time to test them, I will update once I confirm if it does.

Comment: Given there isn't an `@AfterDelete` method, how does one get the `id` of a recently deleted/removed entity? I'm trying to use `beforeRemove` but it doesn't give access to the underlying document/row.

Comment: @HarryCramer As mentioned in one of the [following discussion of the issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3739#issuecomment-473509571) "The subscriber does not have `beforeDelete`/`afterDelete` methods. You need to use remove method to get the entity information"

Comment: Did not find in the documentation, but `remove()` also seems to mutate passed object by deleting the `id` field...

Comment: unable to understand `remove` method, how does it removes an entity from db table structure point of view? Does it clear the whole table associated with that entity?